# Front end post editor which is actively developed

Tags: front-end

I'm trying to find a simple editor for posting content from the front end of a community site.

I will only need to submit one post type (defined in the site configuration) and posts will contain text and images only.

I have seen numerous front end editors, but they are either not supported anymore or cost a fortune.

Can anybody suggest a front end post editor which is still receiving updates in 2017?
The closest I found to what I'm looking for was Raptor, but that is not longer available.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default [wp_edtior](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) in your templates to give opportunity your users posting content.

This forum is not good place to find turnkey plugin

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you, I will make the relevant changes ot my theme.

Comment: @Alex if this answered your question you should mark it as correct, although it really should mention `wp_insert_post`

Comment: @TomJNowell I would have accepted it sooner, but as I only just joined this site a few minutes before posting, there was a time waiting time imposed before I could accept answers.

Comment: Aha! Welcome to the site @Alex :)